# Docker Increase OpenAI's Token amount

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, openai-api

When using calling my API host using a local-hosted PostgreSQL database, I was informed that my Prompt Token is 489 and Completion token is 9

Here is how I track my prompt :

```
with get_openai_callback() as cb:
            response = qa({"question": prompt, "chat_history": chat_history})

            print(f"Prompt Tokens: {cb.prompt_tokens}")
            print(f"Completion Tokens: {cb.completion_tokens}")
            print(f"Total Cost (USD): ${cb.total_cost}")
```

Here is what I received in terminal :

```
INFO:     Started server process [87170]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
112 is the number of tokens in my text
Prompt Tokens: 489
Completion Tokens: 9
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60036 - "POST /query HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

However, when I run in the Docker container, with the exact same code, and I have checked the database and the tokens in the database are the same, when I send a prompt to `ChatOpenAI`, it tells me that :

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 13332 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.
```

The code is exactly the same and the only difference is that Docker does not allow using localhost, so I switched to use a db in `docker-compose.yml`. Does anyone know what happened?

I have tried dropping all the table before loading data into the SQL and cleaned up the database.

Also checked the number of rows, it seems exactly same